# Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[image: хотела открыть отправленный мне проект но не получается]

пробовала менять версии тоже не получается выходит 2 ошибки

```
1) Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.

2)Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.StopExecutionException: Your project path contains non-ASCII characters. This will most likely cause the build to fail on Windows. Please move your project to a different directory. See http://b.android.com/95744 for details. This warning can be disabled by adding the line 'android.overridePathCheck=true' to gradle.properties file in the project directory.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас название проекта это кириллица, называйте проекты на латинице и путь к самому проекту тоже должен содержать только латиницу. Другой вариант решения - добавить в файл `gradle.properties(project properies)`:

```
android.overridePathCheck=true
```

Update:

android.overridePathCheck=true is a property that can be used to bypass path checking in the Android Gradle Plugin. This property allows you to ignore path checking, which was introduced to improve the security of Android project builds.

Normally, the Android Gradle Plugin checks file paths in your resources, and if it finds a path that doesn't match the expected structure (for example, not located in the res subdirectory), the build may fail with an error.

Setting android.overridePathCheck=true can be useful in cases where you have specific requirements for the project structure, and you are confident that your changes are safe. However, such usage should be deliberate and applied with caution.

If you don't have specific reasons to change this property, it's better to refrain from using it. Usually, it is recommended to follow the standard Android project structure to avoid compatibility and support issues.

Comment: спасибо за помощь получилось